# How to draw outwards rounded corner in Android Studio with XML

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to make a container background drawable but the design I got from the designer is a bit complicated. I need to create a rectangle that has rounded corners at the top and bottom but the bottom corner curves outward as shown in the following image:

[image: example]

The solution I have in mind right now is to just make a 9-patch drawable using PNG but is there a way to achieve this using only shape drawables in xml or using vector drawables? I am trying to keep all drawable assets as vectors as much as possible. I'm currently avoiding the use of raster images such as PNG. But if there are no other ways, I will have to resort to using 9-patch drawables after all.

Comment: A very simple answer would be a VectorDrawable, you can draw it on Adobe Illustrator to get the perfect shape

Comment: I could draw a vector drawable with Inkscape, but the problem is when I scale the shape up. For instance I only stretch it vertically, the corners will also be skewed.

Comment: You can make it an imageview, and sweet the scale type, then the vector won't get stretched, only scaled

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a drawable resource file with a layer-list
2. Create two other drawable resource file with a selector tag as the parent tag and a child tag of item with another child tag of shape

```
 <selector>
   <item>
      <shape android:shape=“rectangle”>
         <corners android:radius = “50dp”>
         <solid android:color= “@color/orange”>
      </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Second rectangle

```
<selector>
    <item>
       <shape android:shape=“rectangle”>
          <corners android:radius = “50dp”>
          <solid android:color= “@color/gold”>
       </shape>
   </item>
</selector>
```

In the layer-list resource file

```
<layer-list>
    <item android:drawable =“@drawable/the_orange_rectangle_rsc_file”>
    <item android:drawable =“@drawable/the_gold_rectangle_rsc_file”>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I'm not referring to the two rectangles inside. I was referring to the container itself. The one with the weird curves at the top and bottom corners. Those two buttons inside are just there to indicate that I'm making a modal/form.